# how to know on what versions of IOS and Android my flutter application will work

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

So I'm building an application with flutter 3.0.5 How can I know what versions of  IOS and Android my application will run on?
and how can I change them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android `minSdkVersion` in build.gradle, see [Reviewing the Gradle build configuration](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration) for details.

For iOS `iOS Deployment Target` in Build Settings, see [Review Xcode project settings](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios#review-xcode-project-settings) for details.